# How can I get mysql to output a DateTime to Julian day number?

Tags: mysql, ruby

Basically I am using the [MySQL gem for Ruby](http://www.tmtm.org/en/mysql/ruby/), and I have no reasonable support for date comparison. The `Mysql::Time` class only gives me only accessor methods like year, month, second, etc. I could do much better date comparison, if I could turn this into a Ruby DateTime object. How can convert MySQL's DateTime field to a Julian day number which can be passed to [`DateTime.jd`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/DateTime.html#M002792)?

Comment: Be careful of using DateTime.jd as I have discovered that it may not have been intended to be used with DateTime subclass of Date. It is correct for Date classes only. To show this try DateTime.jd(2455145). Then plug that same number into something like here http://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/JulianDate.php   Did you get the correct time? All Julian Day numbers without a decimal should show 12:00 This jd for Ruby conversion using DateTime objects may be a bug. Someone please report it if so as I have no idea where to begin on that. Thanks! Just my two cents on using DateTime.jd().

Comment: I can confirm this from http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/jd/class But since they show a solution I will retract my comment on the bug. It still just seems wrong. There should have been a method like Date has for Date.ajd() that you can just send a julian day number to and still get the time as well. http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Date/jd/class  I'm kind of annoyed that they always use the ellipses to finalize it. Got to do your own thing to actually see it. And notice .ajd() does not offer a proper conversion to include a number DateTime.ajd(2455145.5) as would in my opinion be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [Ruby/DBI](http://ruby-dbi.rubyforge.org/) instead of using the MySQL gem directly. Ruby/DBI should take care of the conversion into standard Ruby classes for you automatically, and as an added bonus feature if you ever change the DBMS you're running, your use of the DBI doesn't change.

Comment: I take it this still uses the mysql gem?

Comment: @Zombies, Yes. Under the hood, it uses the MySQL gem to actually talk to MySQL.

Comment: @Zombies: whichever one you actually used.

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
TO_DAYS(col)+1721060
```

To convert to julian date.

And:

```
FROM_DAYS(col-1721060)
```

to convert from a julian date.

(I'm using the Chronological Julian date which starts at midnight because it's more useful.)

Answer (score 2):

You could use MySQL's [`TO_DAYS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-days) function to get the date as an integer number of days since the year zero (and just add the appropriate offset to have a [Julian Day number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day)), or you could use the [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function to get an integer number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

Comment: The "appropriate offset" is 1721059.5

Comment: @dan04, I think Ruby wants it as an *integer*, without the 0.5, but I'm not sure about that. Some experimentation may be in order.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Mysql::Time
  def to_datetime
    DateTime.civil(year,month,day,hour,minute,second)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This formula is correct from the year 2000 until 2099:

```
Julian_date = (YEAR(date)-2000)*1000 + DAYOFYEAR(date)
```

Comment: Hm, is that side effect feature or a bug though?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    DATE_ADD(CONCAT(substring(julian_date,1,2), '-01-01'), INTERVAL substring(julian_date,3,3)-1 DAY) 
FROM table
```