# Convert julian date to gregorian

Tags: mysql, sql

In a MySQL SQL statement, how can I convert a Julian date to a Gregorian date?

Something like this:

```
SELECT TO_GREGORIAN(myJulianDate) as 'GregorianDate' FROM myTable
```

`myJulanDate` is of type int.

Comment: That answer can't help because the solution proposed was to use a php function. I'm not using PHP.. i'm using a db MySql and I've some julian date i don't know how to convert directly in sql ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get mysql to output a DateTime to Julian day number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170848/how-can-i-get-mysql-to-output-a-datetime-to-julian-day-number)

Answer (score 1):

I think your Julian date is not actually a Julian date because if you have a specific date in MySql, its day of the week is the one that has to be according to Gregorian Calendar.
So your date is in the Gregorian format in my opinion.
Anyway, if you consider the DD/MM/YY part of the date and you suppose to have it in a Julian format, the conversion to do is adding 11 days.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(myJulianDate, INTERVAL 11 DAY) as GregorianDate FROM myTable;
```

Comment: Who says `myJulianDate` is of type date? It can very well be just a varchar.

Comment: Ok.
If it is a varchar, I need to know its format for answering.

Comment: Ok, so I shouldn't answer this question because it is not well explained. Is it right? (since I have not enough reputation for asking more details)

Comment: That are the guidelines yes. If you have 1 more answer that gets  both up-voted and accepted, then you have enough reputation to place comments and to ask these kind of questions.

Comment: Ok, I don't want to be polemic. Now I know it :)
Thanks

Comment: I confirm you i've a Julian Date (for some past reasons), in INT format

Comment: Could you better explain how this "int format" is done, please?

Comment: Are you serious ? What is not clear in INT = Integer date type ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT FROM_DAYS(myJulianDate - 1721060) as 'GregorianDate' FROM myTable
```

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17543674/479156))